Unable to close multiple areas using bpy in blender 4.2.2 LTS
I am building a blender "app" that is meant to be used by people not familiar with blender. They will run a pre-written python script to add some objects to a blender scene and then visualize them in 3D rendered view. Since this only requires the VIEW_3D, I would like to close other areas that are open by default.
The following code used to work smoothly pre-4.2.2LTS
import bpy

# Close properties, dopesheet and outliner
# Default open areas: ['PROPERTIES', 'OUTLINER', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'VIEW_3D']
to_close = []
for area_type in ['PROPERTIES', 'OUTLINER', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR']:
    to_close.append([a for a in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if a.type == area_type][-1])

override = bpy.context.copy()
    
for area in to_close:
    override['area'] = area
    with bpy.context.temp_override(**override): bpy.ops.screen.area_close()
    
# Switch to rendered view upon launch
main_area = [a for a in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if a.type == 'VIEW_3D'][0]
main_space = [s for s in main_area.spaces if s.type == 'VIEW_3D'][0]
main_space.shading.type = 'RENDERED'

but now it throws an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../script.py", line 17, in <module>
    main_area = [a for a in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if a.type == 'VIEW_3D'][0]
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'screen'

As I understand it, temp_override(**override) is like temporarily changing context to override, doing whatever we wanted to do there, and then coming back to the context before override = bpy.context.copy(). However, I found that print(bpy.context.copy()) gave very different outputs before and after ...area_close(), which is confusing.
I have also tried adding the window and region attributes to the override, but it had no effect. I have gone through the documentation and have googled about this a fair bit. All sources seem to indicate that the above code should just work, unless I am missing something extremely silly.
Note that switching the order of main_area = ... and ...area_close() is not an option because I need to use bpy.context later and I face similar problems if the context doesn't return back to what it was before ...area_close().
In summary, I am looking for a direct fix to the above code, or a way to make bpy.context "point" to VIEW_3D after ...area_close() using some indirect means.
